# How to make the label is same line with Textarea.

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm so confused why text area is not really one line with Message. The message is at the bottom, it supposed to be on the top. My code is like this.

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contact-firstcol"> <label for="name">Name</label> </td>
                        <td class="contact-secondcol"> : </td>
                        <td class="contact-thirdcol"> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contact-firstcol"> <label for="email">Email</label> </td>
                        <td class="contact-secondcol"> : </td>
                        <td class="contact-thirdcol"> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contact-firstcol"> <label for="phone">Phone</label> </td>
                        <td class="contact-secondcol"> : </td>
                        <td class="contact-thirdcol"> <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contact-firstcol"> <label for="message">Message</label> </td>
                        <td class="contact-secondcol"> : </td>
                        <td class="contact-thirdcol"> <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contact-firstcol"></td>
                        <td class="contact-secondcol"></td>
                        <td class="contact-thirdcol"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" /> </td>
                </table>
```

and my CSS is here.

```
    table {
    line-height:30px;
}
.contact-firstcol {
    width:100px;
    font-size:17px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
.contact-secondcol {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:'alegreya_sansregular';
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:17px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
.contact-thirdcol {
    width:400px;
    padding-left:20px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
.form textarea {
    width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    max-height:100px;
    line-height: 150%;
}
```

So far I tried to use this way. and it's not working at all.

```
margin-top:-20px padding-top:-20px;
```

Have a look at [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/B3z6Z/). Can you give us any suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vertical-align` of table cells is by default in the `middle`. Just change it to `top`.

http://jsfiddle.net/B3z6Z/1/

```
td { vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: Oh my god, i didnt know table cells is by default in the middle. Your code is really simple as that. Thank you thank you. It works now. :)

Comment: No worries, glad it fixed it for you :)

Comment: and glad to meet you too!

Comment: Yeah thanks! SO is very good place for all programmers indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the css class:

```
.contact-firstcol {  
    width:100px;
    font-size:17px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    border:1px solid white;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I added "vertical-align: top;" to it.